# How can I mock an imported dependency from my function file?

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I'm attempting to mock a config that is being imported in my security file here:

```
import aiohttp
from fastapi import Header, HTTPException
from .util.config import config 

async def get_user_profile_details(
        user_profile_id: str, ..., ...
):
    user_profile_url = f"{config.entity.ENTITY_BASE_URL}/.../..."
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session: 
      async with session.get(user_profile_url, headers=auth_header) as ...
    ....
```

here is my test setup:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from aioresponses import aioresponses
from my_module.security import get_user_profile_details

    @patch('my_module.util.config.es', autospec=True)
    async def test_get_user_profile_details_success(self, mock_config):
        mock_config.entity.ENTITY_BASE_URL = "http://mocked-entity-url"

        user_profile_id = "123"
        ... 
        ...
```

my test is failing even before it gets to this test function.
It imports that `get_user_profile_details`,
goes down its imports `from .util.config import config`
, importing the config and failing when its trying to get an es instance(also in the config setup)

```
class Config(BaseSettings):
   ... 
   ...   
   es = ElasticsearchConfig() #this is what I'm trying to mock
   entity = EntityAPIConfig() 
... 
config: Config = Config()
```

I've tried several ways.

- mocking the config like you see now
- `@patch('my_module.util.config.config', autospec=True)`
- `@patch('my_module.util.Config', autospec=True)`
- tried using a:

```
     async def asyncSetUp(self):
       self.aiohttp_mock = aioresponses()
```

and mocking the request:

```
 self.aiohttp_mock.get(...
```

Here is the error:

```
    es = ElasticsearchConfig()



E   google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Permission denied on resource project test.
```

What is the correct way to mock that config?

Comment: The error is `403 Permission denied`? It is a bit strange.

Comment: Firstly, when it comes to config-like classes, you often mock the entire class, so that you can have different configurations for different tests. Secondly, unless you're doing end-to-end testing, you aim to avoid connecting to external HTTP servers. By having a proxy class for querying Elastic Search, you can mock that proxy and run automated tests using mock responses.

Comment: Just an update here. I didn't end up mocking the config but just pulled the entity config into its own file. So rather than importing the whole config, we just import the entity config stuff. Thanks for the feedback!